# JavaScript - creating a simple function

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble creating a function, that should have two parameters

```
UzelFunkce : function(fn, invFn) {
    //...
}
```

The parameter function should be: `sin`, `cos`, `tan`, `cotg` and `invFs`.. should be: `acsin`, `acos`..

So the function should have these things. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: so where is question?

Comment: You should probably use: `UzelFunkce:function(fn, invFn)` instead of verbose words and reserved words...

Comment: Ok, i have renamed function to fn, and other to invFn, well what I need is that this function should return theese thing (sin cos ...)

Comment: can you explain what you want and provide some sample?

Comment: Well, it is my maturita work, and the whole program should be able to do any electrotechnics callculation. Teacher gave me program, that can modify any equation by using a tree. But now i just have to add a function, that are returning sin cos and invFn to theese function.

Comment: can you provide code sample how you want use it with some input and some output?

Comment: Trythis have solved my question, anyway thank you for your interesd :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// didn't really test this, but the ideas should be there
function UzelFunkce(fn, fnInv) {
    var fns = {
        sin: function(x) return MATH.sin(x),
        cos: function(x) return MATH.cos(x),
        tan: function(x) return MATH.tan(x),
        cot: function(x) return 1/MATH.tan(x)
    };
    var fnInvs = {
        arcSin: function(x) return MATH.asin(x),
        arcCos: function(x) return MATH.acos(x),
        arcTan: function(x) return MATH.atan(x),
        arcCot: function(x) return MATH.atan(1/x)
    };
    if (typeof fns[fn] !== 'undefined'
     && typeof fnInvs[fnInv] !== 'undefined') {
        // both fn and fnInverse are valid according to the object above
        // and allows you to use fns[fn](x) and fnInvs[fnInv](x)

        // or...
        fn = fns[fn], fnInv = fnInvs[fnInv];

        // fn & fnInv are now valid functions based on the string input.
        // I don't suggest editing the parameters/arguments unless you know what you are doing

        // You should also add checks on input, making sure they are strings or w/e
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you get my point :-)